# window.open how to open self in Mozilla and IE

Tags: javascript, window.open

so I´m trying to make window.open function work, however I am not able to see it working correctly in Mozilla neither in IE,  in both is opening a new tab, however it works correctly in Chrome,.. Here´s the thing:

```
<input type="submit" value="<%=I18n._("Register")%>" onclick="window.open('http://url.com')" class="button" />
```

I´ve tried almost everything I guess: location.href, window.self.. etc but nothing seems to work. How can I open this in self?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, sorry, onClick= "window.open('http://url.com')" is what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You are canceling the navigation by submitting the form. You can do the following to prevent the default action (submit the form) and do the navigation instead:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='http://url.com'; return false;" class="button" />
```

I removed the value because you're not submitting the form anyway. Feel free to put it back if you use it for anything else, it shouldn't break anything.